# Using Workbench Moderation state changes as events

Tags: 8, rules, workbench

I would like to use the Rules module to send out emails to specific roles whenever a moderation state change event occurs on a node. So if a node is saved, and it goes from *Draft* to *Needs Review*, this rule would be triggered to send out emails to the *Content Approver* role.

This was possible in the Drupal 7 version of Workbench Moderation and Rules, but not out-of-the-box with the Drupal 8 version of these modules.

Any ideas what to do here to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using [Workbench Email](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_email) to accomplish this on our D8 site, would this work for you?

Comment: Beautiful! Seems to fit the bill :-) It also allows sending emails to people in different Roles which is exactly what we needed. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Since Workbench Moderation is in Drupal Core you can use
https://www.drupal.org/project/content_moderation_notifications

Comment: Cheers! The Content Moderation that comes with core nowadays is definitely the way to go and we've since changed our workflows to use that one. Will look into that notifications module as well, thanks!